# How to use google calendar API in an extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-js-client

I am trying to make an extension that will display the next 10 upcoming events in a popup. I made a similar program in python, but now I want to make it in and extension.

I am using chrome.identity to get my auth token, which works and asks for permissions to manage calendar

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({"interactive": true}, function(token){
    console.log(token);
}
```

My question is, how do I then use this token to request information from the calendar API, from within my extension?

Any help is very much appreciated,

Brad

Comment: From the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity#method-getAuthToken) it self, to get an access token, you need to use the client ID and scopes specified in the [oauth2 section of manifest.json](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/app_identity#update_manifest). The scope that you need with it is the calendar API scope.

You can also try to check the [OAuth](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth) here. Just simply pass the calendar scope here so that you will have an access to the calendar.